# to write a two words to csv which when opened will show as two lines in one excel column

Tags: excel, csv, c#-4.0

I am using C# to to process some data from a notepead which after the processing will be written to a .csv file. I have done that but the problem is that in one column of the .csv file, some words have to appear two or three lines(equivalent to using Alt+Enter in excel column). I did it using Environment.NewLine, \r and \n as well. But I could not pull it off. Is there a way or is it simply not possible? Thanks in advance.
Unnikrishnan, India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`"\"Hallo" + (char)10 + "World\""`

You need ASCII code 10 for line break and quotation marks at begin and and of the multi line string.

But you have to know that the row heights of the multi line cells will not be adapted automatically if you open the csv file in Excel.

Comment: Oh my God!. The answer given by Fratyx suggesting the \"Hallo" + (char)10 + "World\"" is absolutely correct and successful in my case. Thanks very much for the same.–  Unnikrishnan29 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. To be able to say that, I exported from Excel to see the generated file containing a multirow with NotePad, and then tried to import it : it does two cells.

If your need is not the CSV format itself but the ability to view data in Excel, I advise you to generate an Html file, that is well recognized by Excel.

You just have to name it ".xls" to allow final user to open it with a double click. The only problem of this method is a warning security message when you double click on the file.

For example :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.withBorder
{
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="withBorder">
 <tr>
  <td class="withBorder">First line</td>
  <td class="withBorder">with a second field</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="withBorder" style="border-bottom:none;">this is a</td>
  <td class="withBorder" rowspan="2" >with also a second field</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
    <td class="withBorder" style="border-top:none;">multiline test</td>
 <tr>
  <td class="withBorder">Last line</td>
  <td class="withBorder"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To see Html features supported by Excel, you could manually create expected result in Excel, export it to an Html file (only current sheet or a selection), and then see the underlying code.

I always use Html format, because it is a way lot more flexible than CSV. No numbers format problems, color handling, borders, special signs...

Best regards,

Comment: Oh my God!. The answer given by Fratyx suggesting the \"Hallo" + (char)10 + "World\"" is absolutely correct and successful in my case. Thanks very much for the same.

Comment: Thanks as well to Elo. I will examine this answer also. But it takes time for me understand the complexities.

Comment: I think importing html into excel will work only in MS Office 2010 onwards only.Hence I could not import the html file of Elo. I am more comfortable with .CSV files. Best regards. Thanks to @Elo

Comment: It took time for me to under what Elo had suggested. This solution is also working. But I prefer the .csv file because I am more familiar with it.